# Find repeating words in pdf

Tags: pdf, grep

Is there an easy way to find typos like: "Hi, my my name is is John" where "my" and "is" was written twice? I found something similar [here](https://superuser.com/questions/843778/find-repeated-words-in-a-text) using `grep`, but apparently you have to insert the whole text being searched in terminal. This can be very limiting when searching larger text files. Is there a way I can do this searching a whole pdf-file?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of [`pdftotext`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) tool to the `grep` command:

```
pdftotext <pdffile> - |  grep -Eo '(\b.+) \1\b'
```

---

For searching a predetermined string in PDF files there is also a tool called [`pdfgrep`](https://pdfgrep.org). However it won't allow the complex regular expression like in the referenced example.

Comment: great thanks. I tried your approach, but apparently `pdftotext` directly stores the pdf as `txt`-file and your solution did not work for me for whatever reason. What did the trick was this: `pdftotext <pdffile>; less <txtfile> |  grep -Eo '(\b.+) \1\b'`

Comment: Updated the answer, forgot the dash